# How can I invoke an action on the same selection of spinner value

Tags: android, android-spinner

I select the value from spinner and when I select the same value again then no action is performed on the click.

Comment: keep track of the previously selected value... and check whether the current select selected value is previous one

Comment: check present select valu and previous one both are same or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this custom Spinner class...

```
/** Spinner extension that calls onItemSelected even when the selection is the same as its previous value */
public class NDSpinner extends Spinner {

  public NDSpinner(Context context)
  { super(context); }

  public NDSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  { super(context, attrs); }

  public NDSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
  { super(context, attrs, defStyle); }

  @Override public void
  setSelection(int position, boolean animate)
  {
    boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
    super.setSelection(position, animate);
    if (sameSelected) {
      // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
      getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
    }
  }

  @Override public void
  setSelection(int position)
  {
    boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
    super.setSelection(position);
    if (sameSelected) {
      // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
      getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
    }
  }
}
```