# Implementation of custom spinner class?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to implement a spinner that triggers onItemSelected even if the same item is selected. I found the answer is a custom spinner class extending spinner as described here: [How can I invoke an action on the same selection of spinner value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012470/how-can-i-invoke-an-action-on-the-same-selection-of-spinner-value)

What I don't get is how to implement this? I tried creating the new custom spinner class in the same package as my activity class. Then I created an instance of the custom class like this:

```
private NDSpinner customSpinner;
```

Then I initialize the spinner:

```
customSpinner = (NDSpinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
```

When I run it an exception is thrown on the above line:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner cannot be cast to myprofile.NDSpinner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a custom spinner, you have to declare it in your xml layout file.

Instead of

```
<Spinner ... />
```

declare as

```
<com.xxx.myprofile.NDSpinner ... />
```

You need to use full name of the package plus class name for the spinner.

Comment: Okay I tried that but getting a run time exception now? `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "myprofile.NDSpinner" on path: /data/app/myproject.myproject.apk`

Comment: You need to use full name of the package plus class. I'm not sure if `myprofile.NDSpinner` is that.

Comment: Yep that did it, never would of figured that out on my own. Thanks very much!

Comment: And be sure to "Rebuild" project if you changed the class of a view component in your layout xml.